# how can i have conditional formatting for a graph if the bar number is negative and another colour for positive bar? xlxswriter

Tags: python, xlsxwriter

Hi I am looking for a way to do a conditional formatting for a graph if the number is negative and another positive. Is this possible to do with xlxswriter in python

Answer (score 0):

There is an XlsxWriter chart.[add_series()](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/chart.html#chart-add-series) option called `invert_if_negative` that mimics the Excel feature of the same name.

It isn’t currently possible to set the color however, like in newer versions of Excel.